# ASP .NET MVC Windows Authorization not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In the web.config file, I have the following code:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow roles="group1"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

In the windows Local user and group, I have created a group (group1) with some users in it and I am hosting the site on IIS. when I try to open the site, It shows me the Access denied page.

[attached is the page I get when I try to build/run the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDOAr.png)

When I remove the above peice of code, I am able to access the application. I have tried using hostname, computer name, instead of group name and still not able to access the application. I want to know, if I am missing some configuration or done something wrong. This is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

This allows access for only the users which are part of role `group1`

```
<allow roles="group1"/>
```

This blocks the access for ALL users:

```
Deny users="*";
```

When you deny access to all, it should not work, in my opinion.

Comment: What should be the value for the Deny users, then??

Comment: Maybe it works if you first deny all and afterwards accept single ones. Or it works by only allowing specific roles... (meaning, delete the wohle deny users line) Did you ensure that your user is in the role 'group1'? Did you try having a look in the documentation?

Comment: OK, Let me try that way. Yes, I did cross check and I have user in the group1

Comment: Once I remove the Deny users="*"; block, everyone, it is allowing access to everyone.